# How to parse JS Date to specific format with moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I reading moment.js docs but can not find answer on my issue. 
I want to convert JS format date (ISO-8601) to specific format like `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm'` 
I try something like this but it didn't work :

```
var date = new Date();
var dateMoment = moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
console.log(dateMoment);
```

I can also reveice this in just string, but I don't want to convert it like this:
`date.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDay() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes()`

Comment: what if you try moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm'); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the Moment.format() ?

Would be

```
var date = new Date();
var dateMoment = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm");
console.log(dateMoment);
```

in your case

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `format` function as follow:

```
moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm')
```

```js
var date = new Date();
var dateMoment = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
console.log(dateMoment);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

## Resources

- [Moment.js 2.20.1](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Use below snippet

```
var date = new Date();
var dateMoment = moment(new Date()).format( 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
console.log(dateMoment);
```

Check in detail docs [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Use format

```
moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
```